# In Spyder: where do I find the Qt and PyQt version?

Tags: qt, github, pyqt, version, spyder

Where do I find the Qt and PyQt version in Spyder?

Context.
This is a very simple question, almost too simple to ask for.
On GitHub, when creating an issue in the Spyder project, I was asked to post the Qt and PyQt version. I did not know about it and I tried some general research first without a quick idea. I had the idea of looking into Spyder only afterwards. That is why I document this here, even though it is totally obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Help>"About Spyder"

[image]

Here it is Qt 5.9.6, PyQt 5.9.2

(the "PyQt5" is the tag here at SO as well, of course "PyQt5 5.9.2" is actually doubling the 5, it is enough to write "PyQt 5.9.2")